# Codeigniter 4 not working in Latest PHP 8

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have installed the latest version of xampp with PHP 8.0 and downloaded the latest version of codeigniter 4 and tried to run it.
But it is showing controller method not found how to fix this issue.
I am helpless

[Here is the Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUGDX.png)

Comment: Please provide more details on the error stack trace.

Comment: When you use a third-party framework you need to run it on the PHP versions the framework supports. According to [their download page](https://codeigniter.com/download) it barely supports PHP 5.6+ (the 7.2 version is under development, or they forgot to update docs).

Comment: Their current [master branch](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/composer.json#L8) claims to support PHP/8.0. What version are you using? Did your code (which you haven't shared) really work in earlier versions?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález even thou it still says in the downloads page that codeigniter 4 is the up and coming version that version is already the current one and by the tags OP posted is the one he's using. So PHP 8 is supported. Now he just needs to give us more information about the errors he's getting.

Comment: @marcogmonteiro You're right. "Latest version" must refer to the 4.0.4 release and its composer.json file states `"php": ">=7.2"`, so 8.0 is either unsupported or not tested. But it'd only be a PHP/8 issue if the same code works in 7.2+, which is unclear.

Comment: I tried all what I can but didn't helped for me.
I tried to find issue on codeigniter forum but didn't get any solution for this problem

Comment: So I will have to wait for their test till then I have to develop my application in PHP 7.4???

Comment: check the logs file. `writable->logs->log file`

Comment: I checked log files also there is nothing Whenever I am trying to run the project it is giving the same error

404 - File Not Found
Controller method is not found: index

Comment: you have update all to point localhost/project/public/

Comment: I have done all changes

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter 4.1.0 released - now supporting PHP 8

https://davehollingworth.com/blog/codeigniter-4-1-0-released (3rd Feb 2021)